# Ionic3 - How to implement a persistent chat system with Storage provider?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, chat

I want to create a basic chat system with `Ionic3`.

I want the messages persist on the application, so I think I need to use `Sotrage` provider something similar as they recommend on the official website:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

export class MyApp {
  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

  ...

  // set a key/value
  storage.set('name', 'Max');

  // Or to get a key/value pair
  storage.get('age').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your age is', val);
  });
}
```

But my question is, what do you think is the best way to keep the order of the messages so the application load them properly?

Maybe doing something like...

**when saving a message:**

```
// this is just a quick idea. please, improve it if possible

let message = {
    channel: <channel>,
    timestamp: <timestamp>,
    from: <from>,
    to: <to>,
    content: <content>,
}
storage.set('message', {});
```

**when retrieving the full channel message:**

```
??? how to apply filters to retrieve messages from an specific channel in the proper order ???
```

My doubt here is due to that I don't see the Storage provider have special methods for filtering data and do fancy things. So I'm looking for recommendations on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use native storage, just remember to join your new message to the old object and save it again.

Then inside html you iterate object with ngFor and pipe `*ngFor="let message of messages | orderBy : ['timestamp']"`

Other way to do this, is to use sqlite package for ionic. It's like normal database then https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite/

Comment: I think this is the best answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

For the 'fancy things' you can use [LokiJS](https://github.com/techfort/LokiJS). LokiJS is an in-memory database and has collections that you can chain find/sort/filter/map etc... The complete database can be saved to the ionic storage as json object.

The website http://lokijs.org is currently offline.
Documentation is online [here](https://rawgit.com/techfort/LokiJS/master/jsdoc/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use observables.

Localstorage returns promises, so you could use Observable.fromPromise(this.localStorage.getMessages()) to turn the returned promise into a Observable

Then `*ngFor="let message of messages | async "`

Could add a Timed subscriber to keep checking localStorage for updates periodically.

Is there any particular reason you want to build a chat yourself?

You could look at intercom, which has a cordova and ionic package.